# How to extract data from table in Fangraphs

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the player names from this [table](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=&splitArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=true&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=1&startDate=2023-03-01&endDate=2023-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&wxTemperature=&wxPressure=&wxAirDensity=&wxElevation=&wxWindSpeed=&sort=22,1) using Scrapy

I've tried this

```
rows = response.css('table tr.is-selected_invalid')
```

Thats just to get the rows but that doesnt even work. I also tried to get the data directly from the table using td.alight-left.fixed but that also got me nowhere. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector:

```
div.table-scroll table tbody tr.is-selected__invalid
```

Note: there are two underscores before "invalid".

Answer (score 0):

The table you are attempting to scrape is rendered via javascript and does not exist within the html you receive back from your request to the url you cite in your question.

Because of this there is no selector that will allow you to access the data with a request to that url.

What you can do alternatively is deconstruct the api request made and receive the full table back as a json object using the request you can see in the network tab of your browsers dev tools.

For example:

```
import scrapy
import json

body ={
    "strPlayerId":"all",
    "strSplitArr":[],
    "strGroup":"season",
    "strPosition":"B",
    "strType":"1",
    "strStartDate":"2023-03-01",
    "strEndDate":"2023-11-01",
    "strSplitTeams":False,
    "dctFilters":[],
    "strStatType":"player",
    "strAutoPt":True,
    "arrPlayerId":[],
    "strSplitArrPitch":[],
    "arrWxTemperature":None,
    "arrWxPressure":None,
    "arrWxAirDensity":None,
    "arrWxElevation":None,
    "arrWxWindSpeed":None
}
headers = {
    "Content-Type":'application/json'
}

class TableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "table"
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/splits/splits-leaders", method="POST", body=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield response.json()
```

PARTIAL OUTPUT

```
2023-09-14 19:04:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/splits/splits-leaders> (referer: https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=&spl
itArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=true&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=1&startDate=2023-03-01&endDate=2023-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&wxTemperature=&wxPressure=&wxAirDensity=&wxElevation=&
wxWindSpeed=&sort=22,1)
2023-09-14 19:04:31 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/splits/splits-leaders>
{'k': ['Season', 'playerName', 'TeamNameAbb', 'G', 'PA', 'AB', 'H', '1B', '2B', '3B', 'HR', 'R', 'RBI', 'BB', 'IBB', 'SO', 'HBP', 'SF', 'SH', 'GDP', 'SB', 'CS', 'AVG', 'playerid'], 'v': [['2023', 'Miguel Ca
brera', 'DET', '86', '320', '290', '73', '54', '16', '0', '3', '17', '29', '27', '0', '66', '1', '2', '0', '11', '0', '0', '0.25172414', '1744'], ['2023', 'David Peralta', 'LAD', '119', '378', '351', '94',
'66', '20', '1', '7', '42', '51', '19', '1', '65', '2', '6', '0', '7', '4', '1', '0.26780627', '2136'], ['2023', 'Carlos Santana', '2 Tms', '132', '559', '497', '116', '68', '29', '0', '19', '69', '73', '59
', '0', '98', '0', '3', '0', '6', '6', '0', '0.2334004', '2396'], ['2023', 'Tommy Pham', '2 Tms', '112', '420', '376', '100', '56', '26', '2', '16', '49', '62', '38', '1', '94', '2', '4', '0', '10', '20', '
3', '0.26595745', '2967'], ['2023', 'Anthony Rizzo', 'NYY', '99', '421', '373', '91', '65', '14', '0', '12', '45', '41', '35', '1', '97', '12', '1', '0', '10', '0', '3', '0.24396783', '3473'], ['2023', 'Mik
e Moustakas', '2 Tms', '107', '370', '337', '85', '58', '15', '0', '12', '43', '47', '23', '1', '90', '3', '7', '0', '7', '0', '0', '0.25222552', '4892'], ['2023', 'Jason Heyward', 'LAD', '108', '325', '283
', '76', '44', '18', '0', '14', '53', '38', '33', '1', '56', '3', '3', '0', '6', '2', '2', '0.26855124', '4940'], ['2023', 'Giancarlo Stanton', 'NYY', '91', '373', '333', '66', '32', '11', '0', '23', '42',
'57', '36', '3', '106', '2', '1', '0', '9', '0', '0', '0.1981982', '4949'], ['2023', 'Justin Turner', 'BOS', '132', '570', '505', '143', '92', '28', '0', '23', '84', '94', '49', '0', '96', '10', '6', '0', '
10', '4', '0', '0.28316832', '5235'], ['2023', 'Robbie Grossman', 'TEX', '102', '386', '328', '79', '45', '23', '1', '10', '56', '48', '48', '0', '90', '2', '8', '0', '7', '0', '0', '0.24085366', '5254'], [
'2023', 'Aaron Hicks', '2 Tms', '78', '267', '234', '61', '44', '8', '1', '8', '40', '34', '32', '1', '60', '0', '1', '0', '2', '3', '0', '0.26068376', '5297'], ........., 'pt': 260, 'auto': 'True', 'dev': 'BIS'}
2023-09-14 19:04:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```